# Jquery close issue for popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have created a popup box with a form inside that is intended to open on page load. My issue is that when I create a button to close page on click using js nothing is happening. I have tried hide and fadeout. Please help!

Below is my most recent code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Visitor.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.pop-outer{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.pop-inner{
background-color: #fff;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
padding: 25px;
margin: 15% auto;

}


</style>
<script> 
$("document").ready(function(){
$(function() {
    $(".pop-outer").fadeIn('normal');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("close").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
});</script>

<script>



</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="pop-outer"  >
    <div class="pop-inner ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">
    <button onclick="close">X</button>
    <form action="visitor.php" method="post">

    <div class="section"><span>1</span>Basic Information
        <div class="inner-wrap ">
            First Name <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            Last Name <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="section"><span>2</span>Contact Information
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            Email Address <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            Telephone Number <input type="number" placeholder="Phone Number">

        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="section"><span>3</span>Visit Us
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            When do you plan on visiting?<input type="date" placeholder="Select a date">
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="section"><span>4</span>Stay Connected
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            Would you like to added to our email list?<br>
                <input type="radio" name="emailblast" value="Yes"> Yes! I would love to be connected with Hopewell!
                <input type="radio" name="emailblast" value="No"> No. I am not interested.</label>
    </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="button-section">
            <input type="submit">
         </div> 
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="pop-outer hidden"  >
    <div class="pop-inner ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">
    <button class="close">X</button>
    <form action="visitor.php" method="post">

    <div class="section"><span>1</span>Basic Information
        <div class="inner-wrap ">
            First Name <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            Last Name <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="section"><span>2</span>Contact Information
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            Email Address <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            Telephone Number <input type="number" placeholder="Phone Number">

        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="section"><span>3</span>Visit Us
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            When do you plan on visiting?<input type="date" placeholder="Select a date">
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="section"><span>4</span>Stay Connected
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            Would you like to added to our email list?<br>
                <input type="radio" name="emailblast" value="Yes"> Yes! I would love to be connected with Hopewell!
                <input type="radio" name="emailblast" value="No"> No. I am not interested.</label>
    </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="button-section">
            <input type="submit">
         </div> 
    </form>
    </div>
```

```
css -->

    .hidden {
    display:none;
    }

js-->

$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".pop-outer").show();
    $(".close").click(function(event){
        $(".pop-outer").hide();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

changed your close function by adding a selector(id#)

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
$(function() {
    $(".pop-outer").fadeIn('normal');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#close").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".pop-outer").toggle();
    });
});
});
```

```css
.pop-outer{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.pop-inner{
background-color: #fff;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
padding: 25px;
margin: 15% auto;

}
```

```html
<script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div class="pop-outer"  >
    <div class="pop-inner ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">
    <button id="close">X</button>
    <form action="visitor.php" method="post">

    <div class="section"><span>1</span>Basic Information
        <div class="inner-wrap ">
            First Name <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            Last Name <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="section"><span>2</span>Contact Information
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            Email Address <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            Telephone Number <input type="number" placeholder="Phone Number">

        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="section"><span>3</span>Visit Us
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            When do you plan on visiting?<input type="date" placeholder="Select a date">
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="section"><span>4</span>Stay Connected
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            Would you like to added to our email list?<br>
                <input type="radio" name="emailblast" value="Yes"> Yes! I would love to be connected with Hopewell!
                <input type="radio" name="emailblast" value="No"> No. I am not interested.</label>
    </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="button-section">
            <input type="submit">
         </div> 
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:

You have written onclick "close".
it should be like: class="close" or id="close".
Following is change made in HTML

```
 <button class="close">X</button>
```

Next thing you need to write code to close popup outer:
change made in JS is :

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(function() {
       $(".pop-outer").fadeIn('normal');
   });
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".pop-outer").hide();
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **.(dot)** for class and there is also you are not used **fadeOut** for hide the modal **(popup)**. I hope you can find what is error in your code.

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".pop-outer").fadeIn();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".pop-outer").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.pop-outer{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.pop-inner{
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 5% auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div class="pop-outer">
    <div class="pop-inner ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">
    <button class="close">X</button>
    <form action="visitor.php" method="post">

        <div class="section"><span>1</span>Basic Information
            <div class="inner-wrap ">
                First Name <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
                Last Name <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="section"><span>2</span>Contact Information
            <div class="inner-wrap">
                Email Address <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                Telephone Number <input type="number" placeholder="Phone Number">

            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="section"><span>3</span>Visit Us
            <div class="inner-wrap">
                When do you plan on visiting?<input type="date" placeholder="Select a date">
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="section"><span>4</span>Stay Connected
            <div class="inner-wrap">
                Would you like to added to our email list?<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="emailblast" value="Yes"> Yes! I would love to be connected with Hopewell!
                    <input type="radio" name="emailblast" value="No"> No. I am not interested.
            </div>  
        </div>

            <div class="button-section">
                <input type="submit">
             </div> 
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code your fadein and fadeout open and close popup issue resolve

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Visitor.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.pop-outer{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.pop-inner{
background-color: #fff;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
padding: 25px;
margin: 15% auto;

}


</style>
<script> 
$("document").ready(function(){
$(function() {
    $(".pop-outer").fadeIn('normal');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#close").click(function(event){  
        event.preventDefault();
           $(".pop-outer").fadeOut('normal');
    });

});
});</script>

<script>



</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="pop-outer"  >
    <div class="pop-inner ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">
    <button id="close">X</button>
    <form action="visitor.php" method="post">

    <div class="section"><span>1</span>Basic Information
        <div class="inner-wrap ">
            First Name <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            Last Name <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="section"><span>2</span>Contact Information
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            Email Address <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            Telephone Number <input type="number" placeholder="Phone Number">

        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="section"><span>3</span>Visit Us
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            When do you plan on visiting?<input type="date" placeholder="Select a date">
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="section"><span>4</span>Stay Connected
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            Would you like to added to our email list?<br>
                <input type="radio" name="emailblast" value="Yes"> Yes! I would love to be connected with Hopewell!
                <input type="radio" name="emailblast" value="No"> No. I am not interested.</label>
    </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="button-section">
            <input type="submit">
         </div> 
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the input. I was able to get it to work by using the following code.

```
<script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-
1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<style>
.pop-outer{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.pop-inner{
background-color: #fff;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
padding: 25px;
margin: 15% auto;
}



</style>
<script> 
$("document").ready(function(){
$(".pop-outer").fadeIn('normal');
$(".close").click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        $(".pop-outer").hide();
    });

});
</script>

<body>
<div class="pop-outer">
    <div class="pop-inner ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">
    <button class="close">X</button>
    <form action="visitor.php" method="post">

    <div class="section"><span>1</span>Basic Information
        <div class="inner-wrap ">
            First Name <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            Last Name <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="section"><span>2</span>Contact Information
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            Email Address <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            Telephone Number <input type="number" placeholder="Phone Number">

        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="section"><span>3</span>Visit Us
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            When do you plan on visiting?<input type="date" placeholder="Select a date">
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="section"><span>4</span>Stay Connected
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            Would you like to added to our email list?<br>
                <input type="radio" name="emailblast" value="Yes"> Yes! I would love to be connected with Hopewell!
                <input type="radio" name="emailblast" value="No"> No. I am not interested.</label>
    </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="button-section">
            <input type="submit">
         </div> 
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```